# Как добавить Macro IDE в VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Во вкладке Средства -> Macros нет пункта Macros IDE: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял у меня просто он не установлен, но как его добавить в VS? В VS Installer я не нашел ничего подобного, кроме как пакета "Разработка расширений Visual Studio" и его скачивание не помогло

Comment: а что вообще такое macros?

Comment: это у вас расширение какое-то?

Comment: Я погуглил и узнал,  что можна писать расширение под VS (макросы),  но для этого нужна эта самая Macro IDE(по крайнеймере,  она присутствуетво всех гайдах, которые я нашел). Но нигде не сказано, как её внедрить в VS

Comment: @user7860670, я качал ещё [это](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) помимо расширения  "Разработка расширений Visual Studio". Больше никаких расширений нет

Comment: Макросы - это не расширения, это просто записанная последовательность нажатых клавиш.

Comment: Пусть будет так, @user7860670

Comment: В старых версиях Студии были встроенные макросы. Потом их выпилили (гады), а я пользовался... У вас либо скриншот от старой версии Студии, либо с каким-то расширением. Вот результат поиска по слову [macro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=macro&target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance). Я использовал [Visual Commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander). Другие, кроме него и Macros for Visual Studio, - не то.